# Trying to add css link to file but it fails because there is a space in the path

Tags: html, css

C:\Users\abc xyz\Downloads\link-to-a-stylesheet\css

The editor shows the path after abc in green and it does not work.

Comment: what is the issue??

Comment: Aside- don't use absolute paths, paths must be relative

Comment: So I cannot use absolute paths or its just that using relative paths is better?

Also,
All the paths everywhere use the slash /, but windows uses a backslash \.
Which is correct?

Comment: Try replacing the spaces with %20.

Comment: what exactly is the question? what does not work? what are you doing, and what are you working with?

Comment: Absolute paths are bad because if you upload it to a server or move the file/folder, the path will change. Using relative paths lets you move the root folder anywhere. And use /

Comment: both absolute paths and relative paths have their cons and pros. But right now we need to know more of the problem to help you. It looks like the space is the problem, so just remove/replace the space.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the spaces with %20.

```
C:\Users\abc%20xyz\Downloads\link-to-a-stylesheet\css
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score -1):

Try surrounding the path in quotes:

```
'C:\Users\abc xyz\Downloads\link-to-a-stylesheet\css'
```

Answer (score -1):

To begin with (since the question is kinda vague) change the abc xyz to something like abc_xyz. Spaces are never good for webbased links.

Hope that helps already!

Comment: Whilst I would agree to never have spaces in your path, doing this could cause some pretty disastrous effects. You can easily remedy this by just replacing the space in the call with %20, without having to rename the directory. Avoid that at all costs.

Comment: I am trying to link a css stylesheet to a webpage.
The stylesheet is stored in a local folder on my computer.
The problem is when I enter the absolute path it comes like C:\Users\andy hudson\Downloads\link-to-a-stylesheet\css and it does not work.
Although using relative path did solve my problem